# Type deduction in function composition

Tags: haskell, type-parameter

Hello i have a type with a type parameter:

```
data A=A1| A2 deriving (Show)
data B=B1| B2 deriving(Show)
data C a=C{var::a,var2::Int}

getters=[show . var,show .var2]
```

I get the following error in the `getters` at `show . var` :

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `show'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        getters:: [Worker a0 -> String]
```

Do i have to explicitly state the type ,something like :  `show. (var::B)`.I do not really understand the error since both types `A` and `B` are implementing `Show`

Comment: What happens if you write `getters :: Show a => [C a -> String]`? Why are `A` and `B` relevant here? You here did *not* specify that the `a` in `C a` is per se `A` or `B`.

Comment: If you capitalize `a` in the type of `var` this should typecheck.

Comment: I wanted the getters to be just an expression not a method.

Comment: I do not want to capitalize `a` i want the `var` to be polymorphic.I want  the freedom `var` to be a type that implements `Show`.Oh and now i realise you must specify what implementation it is between `A`-s and `B`-s.

Comment: Note that `a` could not only be `A` or `B`, but also `String, Bool, [[(A, Char)]], ..`. There are infinitely many showable types that could be used in `C a`.

Comment: Ok so i think what i wanted to know is the following: Can you impose a  constraint on a type parameter of a type? Something like: given a `class Myclass a` and a type `MyType` that implements it ,and a type `data C (a::Myclass)=C{ var::a}`.So can i impose a type parameter to implement a certain typeclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit*: updated below to answer your follow-up question.

To answer your original question, this is just a situation where the type checker needs a little help.  You can get your code to type check by adding an explicit signature for `getters`, as @WillemVanOnsem has suggested:

```
data A = A1 | A2 deriving (Show)
data B = B1 | B2 deriving (Show)
data C a = C { var :: a, var2 :: Int }

getters :: (Show a) => [C a -> String]
getters = [show . var, show . var2]
```

or, alternatively, by turning on the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` GHC extension, as @DanielWagner points out.  After doing either of these, the following works fine:

```
> map ($ C A1 10) getters
["A1","10"]
> map ($ C B2 10) getters
["B2","10"]
>
```

This signature doesn't make `getters` a "method", if your comment about methods was directed at Willem.  It's still a polymorphic expression with type `[C a -> String]` (for any type `a` with a `Show a` constraint).

**Update:** As per your comments, you *think* you want to define a data type with a constraint on the type of one or more of its fields.  (You don't *actually* want to do this -- you just think you do -- but who am I to stop you?)

So, to do this, you'll need to enable the `DatatypeContexts` extension and write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}

class Mytypeclass a where
  whatever :: a -> String

data Mytypeclass a => MyType a = M { var :: a, var2 :: a }
```

The compiler will generate a warning that this extension was deprecated because it was widely considered a misfeature and removed from the language.

Now, you can define:

```
getters = [whatever . var, whatever . var2]
```

This will give you an error, though a different error message than before, after which you can either add the signature:

```
getters :: (Mytypeclass a) => [MyType a -> String]
getters = [whatever . var, whatever . var2]
```

or else enable the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension in order to get it to compile, just like before.

Comment: GHC's type system is perfectly capable of doing this without help -- just use the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension.

Comment: Thank you for your response.What i wanted to achieve was actually the following: Given a type with a type parameter i wanted to put a constraint on that type parameter. E.G: `data MyType (a::Mytypeclass)=M{var::a}` where `Mytypeclass` is implemented by some types.I  want a `type parameter` to implement a certain `typeclass`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Generally: don't. Instead, annotate values whose type mentions `MyType` with the class constraint; e.g. `foo :: Mytypeclass a => MyType a -> ...`.

Comment: Yes but this is for `methods` and `typeclasses` ..so you say it is not recommended for `types.`.